# What does "not even close" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, synonyms

I was watching [a Matt Damon interview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFB93d4-56o&t=2m15s) on YouTube. In it, the interviewer asked Matt

> Do you remember? Can you speak any of the languages you spoke?

Matt replied

> Not even close

What does that mean? Of course, I can guess that it means "never" or "not at all". Is my guess right? Can I use another word or sentence instead of that? Lastly, is it slang?

Comment: Given that the question was not as you had originally transcribed, does Matt's answer make more sense now?

Comment: If someone said 2+2=5, you might reply that that was close but not correct. If he said that 2+2=112, you could say that is "not even close".

Comment: wow..thanks for you:Kitb,Matt and Jay. I'm really happy for you to help me. I wanna say "too much thanks!"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means 'that's nowhere near the truth'. It isn't slang, but it's likely to be found only in informal contexts.